# SAP GUI VBScript to cut & paste in chunks with data alteration

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui, sap-basis

To get around a runtime error I need to read from an SAP table AGR_1251 in chunks using VBScript when I run a (SE16 | AGR_1251) query. I get this error TSV_TNEW_PAGE_ALLOC_FAILED - No more storage space available for extending an internal table.

As a work around, we manually copy 750 roles from the user by roles at a time, add a "*" to those that end with a certain character, then paste this back into the multiple select dialog to get the the AGR_1251 extract results in chunks.

I can't figure out how to do this in vbscript. How do I programmatically chunk this data? Ideally I would deduplicate it as well, but its not required.

The code has to run on both vbscript and in javascript, so I can't use excel or other windows tools like wscript. The best idea I have so far is to scroll through and copy just the roles to a file, read them back into an array and dedupe as I read them, then alter them, then loop back through the list to chuck out the results.

This is WAY above my nearly nonexistant vbscript skills. I can't be the only one who has had this problem. Can anyone point me to examples code that does this?

I'm open to suggestions on a better approach as well. I think my solution is fugly to say the least.

Comment: I don't think your going to find some canned code to do this. SAP Scripting in VBScript is generally very specific to whatever you are running. This feels like a probelm that might be better be solved with an RFC enabled ABAP routine, ABAP writing data out to the file system for consumption, or a SOAP service written to get at this data.

Comment: Also, I can't imagine how you would do this in javascript. At least with vbscript you could hook into the `SAPFEWSELib` library on the computer. I really think you need an SAP developer to help whip up a REST API to get whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this code is fugly with some unneeded variables, but it works.

```
Sub Save_AGR_1251s(Tcodes_array,Chunk_size)
    Go_AGR_1251
    writelog("Processing " & ubound(Tcodes_array) & " Tcodes in AGR_1251...")
    k = 0
    s = Chunk_size
    max = ubound(Tcodes_array)
    part = 0
    roles_processed = 0
    For i = 0 To max Step s
        Go_AGR_1251
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtMAX_SEL").text = ""
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtMAX_SEL").setFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtMAX_SEL").caretPosition = 11
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_I1_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
        k = i + s
        counter = 0
        part = part + 1
        If k > max Then k = max End If
        For j = i To k-1
            ' writelog("Save_AGR_1251s Processing Tcode: " & Tcodes_array(j))
            If (Tcodes_array(j) <> "STMS" or Tcodes_array(j) <> "SCC4") Then
                'NOTE: The slow insert is used on XXXX Prod as a work around to odd UI behavior - change with caution - But SLOW!!
                session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,7]").setFocus
                session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,7]").text = Tcodes_array(j)
                session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,7]").caretPosition = 1
                'VKey 13 = Shift-F1 (insert new row)
                session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 13
                If Debug_flag = True Then
                    writelog("i=" & i  & "  j=" & j  & "  k=" & k  & "  s=" & s &" max=" & max &"  counter= " & counter)
                    writelog("part =" & part & "  roles= " & roles & "roles_processed="& roles_processed & "  Tcodes_array= " & Tcodes_array(j))
                End If ' Debug_flag 
                counter = counter + 1
                roles_processed  = roles_processed  + 1
            End If ' Tcodes_array
        Next 'for j to k
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").setFocus
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").caretPosition = 13
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 45
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").select
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").setFocus
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = dir
        file_name = AGR_1251_filename & "_Part_" & part & c_dash & postfix & Datafile_ext
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = file_name
        writelog("Saving file: " & dir & file_name)
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILE_ENCODING").text = File_encoding
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").setFocus
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").caretPosition = 16
        session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 11
        Go_Home
    Next ' For i
End Sub
```

Note that you can do this much faster on most systems by simply doing this

```
for i = 1 to 100
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1," & 7  & "]").text = "Test " & i
next 'for i
```